# Can't find any special indices

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongomatic

I'm using [mongomatic](https://github.com/mongomatic/mongomatic) gem

Here's a list of indices:

```
Address.collection.index_information #=>
{"_id_"=>
  {"v"=>1, "key"=>{"_id"=>1}, "ns"=>"downloader_test.proxies", "name"=>"_id_"},
 "address_1"=>
  {"v"=>1,
   "key"=>{"address"=>1},
   "unique"=>true,
   "ns"=>"downloader_test.proxies",
   "name"=>"address_1"},
 "randomizer_1"=>
  {"v"=>1,
   "key"=>{"randomizer"=>1},
   "ns"=>"downloader_test.proxies",
   "name"=>"randomizer_1",
   "2d"=>true}}
```

When I'm trying to use $near operator in query i got such error:

```
Address.collection.find_one('randomizer' => { '$near' => [129, 0] }) #=>

Mongo::OperationFailure: can't find any special indices: 2d (needs index), 
2dsphere (needs index)
```

I can't understand why it doesn't work, it has index for randomizer but can't use it.

What might be a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with setting up the index

Instead of

```
Address.collection.create_index("randomizer", '2d' => true)
```

should be as

```
Address.collection.create_index("randomizer" => '2d')
```

Answer (score 1):

This also happens when your values for the location array are imported as strings instead of floats.  Make sure your seeds come in with .to_f or that you're not setting the values as strings.